# ionic - navigator.app.exitApp() not working

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

Is there any way to kill app on iOS for ionic? I've tried ionic.Platform.exitApp() as well as navigator.app.exitApp()...both didn't work. I also tried this plugin: https://github.com/joycorp/cordova-plugin-exitapp but didn't work as well.

Is it possible to do this? The app is for enterprise use only and won't be distributed through App Store so no worries about being rejected.

Comment: Can you use ionic-angular `Platform` modules exitApp() function.

Comment: @da32 found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly work

```
if (navigator.device) {
   navigator.device.exitApp();
}
```

I have not tested it before

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator['app'].exitApp();
```

Try this